# How to add user form as an icon/button to ribbon and show userform but still able to work with Excel File?

Tags: excel, vba

When I user the user form, I have to:

1) Alt + F11

2) Choose the Form

3) Run

4) Close the Form

5) Go back to Excel

Excel will not allow me to do anything if the form is not closed. Is there anyway to let me put a little icon on ribbon? And keep the user form appear while I am working with Excel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got two parts to your question:

**Adding an icon to the ribbon**: Do you want the macro to be available for all spreadsheets?

- If so, follow [this guide](http://mohammedkb.wordpress.com/2010/09/14/customize-excel-ribbon-and-make-your-macros-default-commands-2/) to save your macro as an Excel Add-in, and then attach it to the ribbon.
- If you only need it in the current spreadsheet, you could simplify things by adding a button to the spreadsheet which activates the macro (use [this guide](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-a-button-and-assign-a-macro-to-it-in-a-worksheet-HP010236676.aspx)), or you could use a shortcut key to invoke the macro directly (use [this guide](http://kb.iu.edu/data/ahbm.html), `Assigning a shortcut to an existing macro` section)

**Keeping the dialog open:** One of the properties of the UserForm is `ShowModal`; you can simply set that to false.  Alternatively, as per the other answer, you can open it with `MyForm.Show vbModeless`.

Note that the properties of the form also allow you to provide a specific screen position too, so that the form isn't in the way while you're working: change `StartUpPosition` to `0 - Manual`, and provide a value for `Top` and `Left`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do that :) You can simply launch the form in `modeless` mode to keep it open and work with the Excel file at the same time

Try this to launch the userform.

```
Sub Sample()
    Userform1.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. If there is a way to put a little icon on ribbon to run the program it will be really nice but I am okay with assign a macro to a button to the excel file.

Comment: Yes you can create an Add-In :) However if it is just to launch the form then might as well assign a macro to a button.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have to create another module and call the userform in that module. After that just put that macro on the ribbon.It may help you.....